# Sacar promedio de una lista anidada en python

Tags: python

Tengo una lista anidada llamada amigos que contiene los siguientes datos: nombre, edad, estatura, peso, genero (m (masculino) o f (femenino) y ciudad.
Sin embargo me piden hallar la edad, estatura y peso promedio de las mujeres de “New York" y no sé como lograrlo, me ayudan por favor?

```
amigos= [
     ["Pedro",55,1.7,60,"m","New York"],
     ["Pepa",50,1.71,55,"f","Buenos Aires"],
     ["Pepe",55,1.8,40,"m","Buenos Aires"],
     ["Pepilla",50,1.8,55,"f","New York"],
     ["Ana",52,1.7,60,"f","Lima"],
     ["Alba",52,1.9,52,"f","Lima"],
     ["Sexi",25,1.75,53,"f","Cancun"],
     ["Julia",25,1.75,47,"f","New York"]
]
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hay varias formas de solucionar ese problema. Una de las soluciones pudiera ser: incializar tres variables en 0 (por ejemplo: `t1 = 0`, `t2 = 0` y `t3 = 0`), luego recorrer la matriz (por ejemplo: `for x in amigos:`) y chequear las condiciones que necesitas `if x[4] == "f" and x[5] == "New York":`. Si la condicional se cumple se acumulan los totales(por ejemplo:  `t1 += x[1]`,`t2 += x[2]`y`t3 += x[3]`). Fuera del `for` puedes imprimir el resultado con el formato que desees. Para el promedio de edad: `t1 / len(amigos) if len(amigos) > 0 else 0` y así con t2 y t3.

Answer (score 1):

Como tienes una lista que contiene otras listas, podrías recorrer la lista principal y con el operador *in* comprobar en cada iteración si dentro de la lista iterada se encuentran los elementos *"f"* y *"New York"*.
Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```py
edad=0
estatura=0
peso=0
numero_de_sumados=0
for persona in amigos:
    if "f" in persona and "New York" in persona:
        edad += persona[1]
        estatura += persona[2]
        peso += persona[3]
        numero_de_sumados += 1

print("La edad, estatura y peso promedio de las mujeres de New York son:")
print(f"Edad: {edad/numero_de_sumados}")
print(f"Estatura: {estatura/numero_de_sumados}")
print(f"Peso: {peso/numero_de_sumados}")
```